# Knockout kobindinghandler update not being called when observable array updated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to create a `jquery ui accordion`that updates when I add values to an underlying observable `array`.  I'm using `jquery1.9.0, jquery-ui-1.11.2` with `knockout 3.2.0` and have simplified the example as much as I can.

I'm new to knockout and novice with `javascript`.  I've also tried the example on the knockout tutorial page to see if it would work.  I'm creating a simple div/h3/div block that is being generated from an observable array, which works fine when the new element is added to the array, the new data is displayed, however it's not regenerating the accordion.

I tried a couple of methods, one that worked had the accordion refresh in a function that did the add to the array however I've read (and believe) that the better solution is to use the kobindinghandler.  This works for the initial data that is in the array, as the accordion is generated but when the new element is added, it's not calling the update function in the handler.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).accordion();
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var options = valueAccessor() || {};
    $(element).accordion("refresh");
  }
};

var viewModelInst = {
  account_data: ko.observableArray([{
    account_id: 1,
    name: "account1"
  }, {
    account_id: 2,
    name: "account2"
  }])
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModelInst);


setTimeout(function() {
  viewModelInst.account_data.push({
    account_id: 3,
    name: 'test'
  });
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<body>
  <div data-bind="foreach: account_data, accordion">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <div>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Maybe I've simplified this too much, any help you can give to get this working or alternative approaches to achieving the same results (the end result here is to have the array loaded from a REST api).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on this a little more, asked a few colleagues and taken code from a working example when using the `bindingHandlers`, working this back into my example.  It seems that the update method is called successfully if the following 2 lines of code are added:

`var value = valueAccessor();
 var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);`

I don't actually do anything with the values but this is enough to get the handler to execute, so when I have my following `$(element).accordion("refresh");` this works as expected.  The full handler code is:

`ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
                init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                    $(element).accordion();
                },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
                    $(element).accordion("refresh");
                }
            };`

You do also have to pass in the `account_data` to the `accordion` binder.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` will not be called in your case since you have not provided the any value from `viewmodel` to the `accordion` binder.

> Knockout will call the update callback initially when the binding is applied to an element and track any dependencies (observables/computeds) that you access. When any of these dependencies change, the update callback will be called once again

Probably the below code will work in your case.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: account_data, accordion: account_data">
<h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Now on changing the `account_data` the binders which uses the `viewmodel` will be called.

Comment: Hi, I've tried the suggestion and added the `account_data` but the accordion is still not updating.  I've also tried with an empty object {} as I have seen this before in other postings, still not working.  I did wonder how the relationship between the `account_data` observable and the handler was managed/set up.